# How to use grep command to diplay entries that are greater than 100k and less than 140k In the last feild of a file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make a grep command to select entries from an employees file.

The employee list file has the salaries as the last field of each of the lines in the file.

How can I use grep to select only the employees that have salaries that are greater than 100000 and less than 140000?

This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to prevent the 100000 results in the list from showing up in the grep results.

```
grep "[1][0-3]....$" emp.lst
```

Here are the results that I get from the grep...

```
$ grep "[1][0-3]....$" emp.lst
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :100000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :130000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :120000
```

Here is the `cat` of the whole file for emp.lst...

```
2233    :a.k. shukla         :g.m.      :sales          :12/12/52  :6000
9876    :jai sharma          :director  :production     :03/12/50  :7000
5678    :sumit chakrobarty   :d.g.m     :marketing      :04/19/43  :6000
2365    :barun sengupta      :director  :personnel      :05/11/47  :7800
5423    :n.k. gupta:chairman :admin                     :08/30/56  :5400
1006    :chanchal sanghvi    :director  :sales          :09/03/38  :6700
6213    :karuna ganguly      :g.m.      :accounts       :06/05/62  :6300
1265    :s.n. dasgupta       :manager   :sales          :09/12/63  :5600
4290    :jayant Chodhury     :executive :production     :09/07/50  :6000
2476    :anil aggarwal       :manager   :sales          :05/01/59  :5000
6521    :lalit chowdury      :director  :marketing:     :09/26/45   :8200
3212    :shyam saksena       :d.g.m     :accounts       :12/12/55  :6000
3564    :sudhir Agarwal      :executive :personnel      :07/06/47  :8000
2345    :j.b. saxena         :g.m.      :marketing      :03/12/45  :140000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :100000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :150500
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :130000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :120000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :190000
```

Comment: Why do you *want* to use the `grep` command for this, and not `awk` (which is a much better tool for the job)? ...oh, *homework*.

Comment: I would have rather used awk, but the instructor wanted me to use exclusively grep. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: If you're in a class and your instructor tells you to use a hammer on a screw, you refuse and use the screw driver instead.  Same situation here.  Use awk.

Comment: lol alright, got it. Thanks man lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a *character-class* of `[1-3]` or `[0-3]` as the second digit and limit the `[0-3]` alternative to a `[1-9]` class at the end. Don't forget to anchor your expression to the end of the line, e.g.

```
$ grep '1[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$\|1[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]$' file
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :130000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :120000
```

Where `1[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$` captures `110000-139999` and `1[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]` ensures values less than `100001` are omitted.

To handle all values, including those not shown in your example, you can extend the expression to check each value and anchor the beginning with a `[:]`, e.g.

```
grep '[:]1[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$\|[:]1[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]\|[:]1[0-3][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\|[:]1[0-3][0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]$\|[:]1[0-3][0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]' file
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 5):

While one could try to fudge numerical comparisons with regex I recommend against it.  Something like `awk` seems more suitable for the task at hand.

```
awk '{if( gensub( /:/, "",1, $NF) > 100000 && gensub( /:/, "",1, $NF) < 140000){print}}' emp.lst
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :130000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :120000
```

Since the format seems to be fixed width I replaced the `:` with nothing to make the numerical comparison on the last field of each line possible.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, Is it possible to do it with just ```grep``` and not ```awk```? I kept only being able to come up with solutions for it using awk. But my instructor wants me to use exclusively ```grep```.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk (or some versions of mawk) for `gensub()`.

Answer (score 5):

Your instructor has gone off the rails as this is a completely inappropriate task for grep, even as an exercise. Unless she's trying to teach you the meaning of [this quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) of course:

```
Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.
```

In any case, the right way to do this in UNIX is:

```
$ awk -F: '100000<$NF && $NF<140000' file
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :130000
0110    :v.k. agrawal        :g.m.      :marketing      :12/31/40  :120000
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that the use of grep was not called for as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use perl compatible regular expressions(`grep -P`) then you can do the following:

```
grep -P ':(?=1[0-3]\d{4}$)(?!100000$)' emp.lst

: - required so that we will have a main expression and not only lookaheads
(?=1[0-3]\d{4}$) - positive lookahead that will match all the numbers less than 140000
(?!100000$) - negative lookahead that will discard 100000 matches
```

This works because lookaheads don't consume characters and the negative one will recheck what was matched by the positive.

If you can't use `grep -P` you can do it with pipes:

```
grep "[1][0-3]....$" emp.lst | grep -v ':100000$'
```

`grep -v` doesn't return what matches so it will filter all lines with `100000`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah... I just copied it from OP's question. The goal was to show that it's possible to nest greps and use`grep -v` to filter matched results.